# Regularity of elliptic operators- no flux boundary conditions

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

It is known that if $U$ is a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ than 
for every $f\in C^{\infty}(\bar{U})$ the solutions to the problem
$$
Lu=f
$$
where $L$ is uniformly elliptic operator with smooth coefficients in $\bar{U}$, of divergence form.
are smooth.

What happen if $U$ is not smooth, only piecwise smooth , e.g., a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Can someone give a reference?

thanks

Comment: As I recall these kinds of results go through with just Lipschitz boundary, but the proof is a bit simpler with piecewise smooth boundary. I'm not sure about a reference though. (Maybe poke around in the elliptic regularity section of Evans)?

Comment: already did, but did not find it there

Comment: Maybe you can try to ake a look at Grisvard's Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains.